# Horizontally Collapse/Extend Images?

Tags: html, css, image

I have 2 images in a container both taking up 50% of the viewers screen. I want to have a collapsible div that extends horizontally from the left image over/on top of the right image when the left image is clicked, is that possible?

Here [is a graphic of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63kSz.jpg)

When Image A is clicked I want a div (B) to extend horizontally over image C, and then collapse once again back under Image A

[Graphic of A&B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d6kZ.jpg)

From my research, I have not quite found what I need and any help would be appreciated. I have tried to collapse the image the normal-vertical way so far but I cant even get that to function. Here is a Jsfiddle of my progress: http://jsfiddle.net/Dunne08/tfwyxksL/6/

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="imageleftcontainer">
        <img alt="270x170" class="leftimage" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dunne08/split/master/images/A.jpg"  /> 
          </div>

          <div class="imagerightcontainer">
        <img alt="C" class="rightimage" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dunne08/split/master/images/C.jpg"  />
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0px;
}

.imageleftcontainer {
    float: left;
    width:50%;
    max-height:100vh;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #000000;

}

.leftimage {
    width: 100%;
}

.imagerightcontainer {
    float: left;
    width:50%;  

    max-height:100vh;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}

.rightimage {
    width: 100%;
}

.container .content {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}
```

Script:

```
$(".imageleftcontainer").click(function () {

    $imageleftcontainer = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $leftimage = $imageleftcontainer.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $leftimage.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $imageleftcontainer.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $leftimage.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3fqsoh4a/25/

```
$(".leftA").click(function(){
    $(".leftB").toggleClass("test");
});
```

I am using the toggle function of jquery to achieve this.

Comment: Nilesh, Perfect. Thats exactly what I needed. Thank You!.

Comment: Now to add the same idea to the right Image I just tried duplicating that script and renaming as rightA & rightB while also adding those classes to the CSS but I've now broke the function of it. Do you know why? My progress: https://jsfiddle.net/Dunne08/qj6gs43k/1/

Comment: Nilesh, is it possible to add the same functionality to the right image? Anything I try doesn't work